# Cassandra Murmur3Partitioner row order

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have the following Cassandra table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE example.posts (
    name text,
    post_topic text,
    post_date timeuuid,
    post_text text,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, post_topic, post_date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_topic ASC, post_date ASC)
```

My partition key is `name` and clustering key is `post_topic, post_date`.

I need to loop through all elements in the table so I execute the query `SELECT * FROM posts` and get data back as follows.

```
   name | post_topic | post_date                            | post_text
   tom  |  cassandra | 86feab80-710d-11e7-898a-176eb9e01b3a |        hi
   tom  |  cassandra | 8a4dd680-710d-11e7-898a-176eb9e01b3a |       bye
   john |  cassandra | 930ee570-710d-11e7-898a-176eb9e01b3a |  whats up
```

I am using the Murmur3Partitioner.

If I want to loop through all the elements in the table and as I do so process them in code one `name` at a time, can I rely on all the rows for the same `name` coming one after the other (e.g. `tom, tom, john`, and not `tom, john, tom`?

According to Cassandra docs `It is important to understand that the order in which partitioned rows are returned, depends on the order of the hashed token values and not on the key values themselves.`

If I have 2 partition keys that generate the same token, then would I potentially get rows for different names mixed up? i.e. if tom and john generated the same token would I get back `tom, tom, john` or could it be mixed up like `tom, john, tom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Different name will generate different token, Murmur3Partitioner make sure of that.**

Cassandra store all your data group by partition key. Cassandra will store your data like below :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   tom   |  cassandra : 86feab80-710d-11e7-898a-176eb9e01b3a  | cassandra : 8a4dd680-710d-11e7-898a-176eb9e01b3a |
|         | ---------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|         |                   hi                               |                  bye                             |    
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|    
|  john   |  cassandra : 930ee570-710d-11e7-898a-176eb9e01b3a  |
|         |----------------------------------------------------|
|         |                whats up                            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can see that all the data with partition key top in the same row in the internal structure of the cassandra. Cassandra scan partition by partition, order by the token of the partition key.

So cassandra will choose a parition and return all the value of that partition continuously. then next partition. **In your case Either "tom, tom, john" or "john, tom, tom"**

Answer (score 0):

> MurmurHash3
>
> The current version is MurmurHash3 which yields a 32-bit
> or 128-bit hash value. When using 128-bits, the x86 and x64 versions
> do not produce the same values, as the algorithms are optimized for
> their respective platforms.

Cassandra will return data for each partition key ordered by clustering key.

In your case data for `name` will be ordered by `post_topic` and `post_date`.

So data returned can be `tom,tom,john OR john,tom,tom`... but it will never be tom,john,tom...

Murmur3 hash will not give duplicate token to different partition key.

**Note:** `Select * from table` might result in timeout if table is huge... Not sure about your use-case... but you might want to have look at spark-cassandra-connector.